# Equipment for programming while walking

Tags: keyboards

I have a condition where I must stand all the time and cannot stop walking but would like to resume programming.

I am looking for a strappable keyboard the would allow me to code on my cellphone will AIDE while walking.

I am looking for a split keyboard that I can wear on my torso while looking at my cellphone or tablet straight downwards or in front. The equipment would look like a life jacket with the keyboard on the sides of the stomach. As part of the same piece or as a hat, the cell phone could be strapped on with a regulatable wire that held the phone or tablet in front of the user.

Comment: Is this a serious question? Not [the boat programming question](https://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/) of this site?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this a few times. E.g. [this](https://8thlight.com/blog/doug-bradbury/2010/02/25/walk-and-code.html), where you use a treadmill with a standing desk. Or [this](http://smarterware.org/2010/07/ikea-jerker-do-it-yourself-treadmill-desk/).

Comment: Looks great, but how do you deal with the noise coming from the treadmill. If you could walk on the ground with something strapped onto your body and a mounted television monitor on the wall then it wouldn't make any noise. Is this possible? Has anyone thought of making this commercially available?

Comment: If you are concerned of the noise only for yourself, maybe a noise canceling headphone would solve this.

Comment: Yes, Bose has some nice ones. They do affect the ear in the long run though I believe. However, my neighbors below would hear the noise from the treadmill and so I don't think it's doable in my apartment.

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson, to my knowledge Bose over-ear headphones don't damage/hurt the ear, but I could see how the in-ear earbuds could damage your ear somehow (as an AirPod user, I do get to a point where my ears become sore from having a hard piece of plastic in your ear for hours on end when my older Beats X didn't have as a big of an issue).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a rare medical condition, I'm not aware of any such market device existing.  You can ask your doctor, who should be familiar with more people in your situation, and might be able to suggest something.

Or, you can make a DIY solution.  Get a strap, such as a guitar strap.  To this strap, attach a surface shaped to your body; a piece of sheet aluminum would be rigid enough and light enough for the job; you might have to cut it yourself with metal scissors.  Make sure to pad the side that touches your body.  Finally, on top of it, you can put a [split keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0089ZV1C4).  If you cut your surface right, it would also have a spot for the tablet.  This should do the job.